# How can I view the signer of a bundle?

Tags: macos, applications, digital-signature, gatekeeper

I have a .bundle that is digitally signed. I can verify this by opening the bundle by selecting "Show Package Contents" and indeed there is a `_CodeSignature` directory underneath the bundle.

However, I am trying to figure out *who* is the signer of the bundle. Is there any way with Xcode, or any other tool, command line or otherwise, to view the certificate that was used to sign the bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the optional command line tools that XCode will install for you, `codesign` is the tool of choice.

Using the Terminal app:

```
$ codesign --display -vv /Applications/GarageBand.app/
Executable=/Applications/GarageBand.app/Contents/MacOS/GarageBand
Identifier=com.apple.garageband
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (i386)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=24489 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=1218+3 location=embedded
Signature size=4169
Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=27
Sealed Resources rules=14 files=2021
Internal requirements count=2 size=500
```

And a non-Apple signed app..

```
$ codesign --display -vv /Applications/iTerm.app/
[snip]
Authority=Developer ID Application: GEORGE NACHMAN
```